# How can we get script failure mail from AirFlow DAG?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working on AirFlow POC, written a DAG which can run a script using ssh on one server. It giving alert if the script fails to execute but if the scripts executed and the task in the script fails it is not giving any mail.

Example: I'm running a script which can take backup of a database in db2. If the instance is down and unable to take the backup so backup command failed but we are not getting any alert as the script executed successfully.

```
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import airflow
import os
import logging
import airflow.settings
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

START_DATE = airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "5,10,15,20,30,40 * * * * *"

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Use this to grab the pushed value and determine your path
def determine_branch(**kwargs):
    """Use this to define the pathway of the branch operator based on the return code from the SSHOperator"""
    ti = TaskInstance(task='t1', execution_date=START_DATE)
    return_code = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(ti.task_ids='SSHTest')
    print("From Kwargs: ", return_code)
    if return_code := '1':
        return 't4'
    return 't3'


# DAG for airflow task
dag_email_recipient = ["mailid"]
# These args will get passed on to the SSH operator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'afuser',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['mailid'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'start_date': START_DATE,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}


with DAG(
    'DB2_SSH_TEST',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='How to use the SSH Operator?',
    schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL,
    start_date=START_DATE,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    # Be sure to add '; echo $?' to the end of your bash script for this to work.
    t1 = SSHOperator(
        ssh_conn_id='DB2_Jabxusr_SSH',
        task_id='SSHTest',
        xcom_push=True,
        command='/path/backup_script',
        provide_context=True,
    )

    # Function defined above called here
    t2 = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_ssh_output',
        python_callable=determine_branch,
    )

    # If we don't want to send email
    t3 = DummyOperator(
        task_id='end'
    )

    # If we do
    t4 = EmailOperator(
        to=dag_email_recipient,
        subject='Airflow Success: process incoming files',
        files=None,
        html_content='',
        #...
    )

    t1 >> t2
    t2 >> t3
    t2 >> t4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure email notifications per task. First you need to configure your email provider, and then when you create your task you can specify "email_on_retry", "email_on_failure" flags or you can even write your own custom hook "on_failure" where you will be able to code your own custom logic deciding when and how to notify.

Here is a very nice Astronomer article explaining all the ins and outs of notifications: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/error-notifications-in-airflow

Comment: Hi Jarek, Thanks for the inputs. Here my issue is script is running fine, but the command inside is failing. Usually we will receive a mail from script if the command fails. But in DAG how can we capture the failure of the command.

Comment: Exactly how I responded - see the article.

Comment: You have various trigger rules which you can follow, if you want to do "something else" after a task failed - if that's what you ask for https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules